# Wordpress - Check if logged as admin with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tp-navigation-menu/
I've modified the number of top pixel from 0 to 26:

```
jQuery('#navbar').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':26 });}
```

but if I am logged in as admin appears the wpadminbar that spoils everything! The menu goes below that bar.
How can I solve this problem?
I imagine I could check if i'm logged top is 56 otherwise 26, but how can i know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will help you

```
  show_admin_bar(false);
```

Put the above line in functions.php in theme file.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook this line in your functions.php

> add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

You can also use this line to specify the user.

> if (!current_user_can(‘edit_posts’)) { show_admin_bar(false); }